# Can I use the SSH tunnel under a VPN as a VPN server?

Tags: ssh, vpn, ssh-tunnel

I am work at home (China mainland). After connected (via `VPN`) to the school IP, I got the permission to `ssh` my computer in campus, but cannot visit `google.com`. However, my computer in campus can visit the `google.com`.

In this case, can I use my computer in campus to provide VPN service for my local machine, under the condition that I have to first build another VPN in order to ssh my campus computer?

Comment: Yes, you can. Simplest is to run client with SOCKS5 proxy (`ssh target.server -D proxyport`) and configuring a browser to use that proxy on localhost, no need to any additional setup, but requires TCP port forwarding enabled on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@Nikita Kipriyanov](https://serverfault.com/users/325117/nikita-kipriyanov). I use the below commands and successfully visited `google.com` on local machine.

```
ssh my_name@server_ip -D 2222
```

And the using the Chrome extension `SwichyOmega` to set the SOCKS5 proxy server by filling the below info:

```
Protocal:SOCKS5
Server:127.0.0.1  # i.e., the localhost
Port: 2222
```